# Flask Yahoo Finance API response does not work for some symbols. Problemset from CS50 Week9

Tags: python, flask, cs50

I facing a problem, that seems to me very interesting. Additional I have no clue how to make it work. Would be nice if someone has any ideas.

The problem is, that for some reason, when I response to the API for some symbols it gives me back an error. I am sure for the Amazon (AMZ), guess they are more, because when I run the CS50 test kit, it runs into the same error.

The code I use is nearly the same as provided to me, added some stuff to find where the error occurs and maybe solve it:

```py
def lookup(symbol):
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # Prepare API request
    symbol = symbol.upper()
    end = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern"))
    start = end - datetime.timedelta(days=7)

    print(int(end.timestamp()))
    print(int(start.timestamp()))

    # Yahoo Finance API
    url = (
        f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(symbol)}"
        f"?period1={int(start.timestamp())}"
        f"&period2={int(end.timestamp())}"
        f"&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
    )

    # Header for response
    """ header = {
        'User-Agent'      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept'          : '*/*',
        'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'DNT'             : '1', # Do Not Track Request Header
        'Connection'      : 'close'
    } """

    # Query API
    try:
        """ response = requests.get(url, cookies={"session": str(uuid.uuid4())}, headers=header) """
        response = requests.get(url, cookies={"session": str(uuid.uuid4())}, headers={"User-Agent": "python-requests", "Accept": "*/*"})
        response.raise_for_status()

        # CSV header: Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
        quotes = list(csv.DictReader(response.content.decode("utf-8").splitlines()))
        quotes.reverse()
        print(quotes)
        price = round(float(quotes[0]["Adj Close"]), 2)
        return {
            "name": symbol,
            "price": price,
            "symbol": symbol
        }
    except (requests.RequestException, ValueError, KeyError, IndexError) as e:
        print(f"An error occured: {e}")
        return None
```

When I response AMZ, the following error occurs:

```
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 18:10:29] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 18:10:29] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 18:25:08] "GET /buy HTTP/1.1" 200 -
1695399914
1694795114
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): query1.finance.yahoo.com:443
An error occured: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AMZ?period1=1694795114&period2=1695399914&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
DEBUG: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com:443 "GET /v7/finance/download/AMZ?period1=1694795114&period2=1695399914&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true HTTP/1.1" 404 38
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 18:25:14] "POST /buy HTTP/1.1" 400 -
INFO: 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2023 18:25:14] "GET /static/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Following the link that comes from the error:

> 404 Not Found: Timestamp data missing.

But the timestamps seem to be there.

So maybe someone know what to do. All works proper in my app, but only this is not working. Please help me :-).

What I have done so far:
I already found where the error seems to be. Tried a few different Symbols. IEX, META, DAX, OMC, WPP work proper, but AMZ, PUB,  not. And the CS50 tested tries some Symbol that seems to work not too, but not sure which.
Tried to use an other header, but the result is the same.
Set the timestamp back `end = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")) - datetime.timedelta(weeks = 52)` but same result, tried it a view hours, days and at least 52 weeks.

Not sure what other troubleshooting steps could be done. Please give advice if there are other stuff too.

Comment: I found the stuffs solution. Tried now the same and interestingly they did not found the two symbols too. So I guess the error is on the API.